# Error in foreign key constraint of table univ/#sql-bf4_4:

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys

I am unable to add a foreign key with a relationship between members and campus tables. The specific fields are set to primary key. The datatypes are also the same.

The tables are:

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| memberid         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lastname         | char(30)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| firstname        | char(30)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| campusaddress    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| campusphone      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| campusid         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| positionid       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contractduration | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc campus;
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| campusid       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| campusname     | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| street         | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city           | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state          | char(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pin            | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone          | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| campusdiscount | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ALTER TABLE members add foreign key (campusid) references campus;
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

OR

```
alter table members add constraint members_campusid_fk foreign key(campusid) references campus;
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Specific error:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2020-02-10 09:23:38 0x2ccc Error in foreign key constraint of table univ/#sql-bf4_4:
 foreign key (positionid) references position:
Syntax error close to:
```

It may be something silly,as I'm an expert in making those. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close, there's a slight missing thing which's the primary key column name(`campusid`) of the parent table (`campus`). Consider using

```
alter table members 
  add constraint members_campusid_fk 
  foreign key(campusid) references campus(campusid)
```

or `constraint members_campusid_fk` part ( the name of the constraint ) might be omitted.

Comment: Thanks a ton. As I said "It may be something silly,as I'm an expert in making those."